# Creating sub directory in SFTP using WinSCP in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I like to create a directory in my SFTP server with WinSCP in C#.

I tried `Sesion.CreateDirectory()` with which I was able to create only one folder level.

I was not able to create more than one folder level.

If I create one folder test I was not able to move the working directory to that folder to create sub-folders. How to create a directory with more subdirectory and create the directory if the subdirectory doesn't exist.

```
session.CreateDirectory("test/Upload/part1/part2");   -notworking
```

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP .NET assembly does not use a concept of working directory.

You should use absolute paths:

```
session.CreateDirectory("/home/user/test");
session.CreateDirectory("/home/user/test/Upload");
session.CreateDirectory("/home/user/test/Upload/part1");
session.CreateDirectory("/home/user/test/Upload/part1/part2");
```

or at least paths relative to initial (home) directory::

```
session.CreateDirectory("test");
session.CreateDirectory("test/Upload");
session.CreateDirectory("test/Upload/part1");
session.CreateDirectory("test/Upload/part1/part2");
```